# Keycloak idp login_hint forwarder

Tags: keycloak

I need to forward username written in Keycloak login page to some idp e.g. github.
So basically. Keycloak login page -> choose idp -> pass automatically username there
I don't want to write username on idp side. I only want to write username on keycloak login page